# how to troubleshoot Radian as VS Code Terminal for R

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

radian (for R) is not starting as terminal in VS Code

There is an extended error message (from python exception?) that is displayed briefly, then the terminal closes and error message comes up:

```
The terminal process 
"c:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts\radian.exe '--nosave', '--no-restore', '--r-binary="C:/program files/R/R-4.1.3/bin/x64/R.exe"'"
terminated with code: 1.
```

If I cut-n-paste the command line into a VS Code terminal - then radian starts perfectly fine. (Works in both a command prompt terminal or a git bash terminal.)

1. How do I stop the terminal closing on error, so that the python exception log can be read ?
2. Is the problem known ? (I suspect its related to VS Code Environment.)

Note: I have `terminal.integrated.inheritEnv: true`

Comment: What do your `settings.json` look like?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the settings that you have above - is it that your `r-binary` option flag is set using forward slashes in your path instead of backslashes? i.e. the flag *should* be:

`--r-binary="C:\program files\R\R-4.1.3\bin\x64\R.exe"`

instead of what you have right now, which is:

`--r-binary="C:/program files/R/R-4.1.3/bin/x64/R.exe"`